# Google API Request Limit For Enterprise

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

I am developing a service using Google Gmail Api for Enterprise.
When testing, I noticed that the API's Rate Limit is different between google free account and gsuite account.
Does anyone know where I can find Google API Request Limits for gsuite?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but hopefully this will help someone in the future.

If you go to support.google.com and search for G Suite Administrator Help and click on the link, it will take you to the G Suit Administrator Help page.  Then go to Manage Your Services and click on Gmail.

On the Gmail-Manage Gmail for your G Suite Team page currently here (https://support.google.com/a/topic/9202?hl=en&ref_topic=9197) look under the section Policies/Abuse Controls.

It lists the limits for sending, receiving and storage limits etc.